# spring bean could not autowire

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-4

I am working a Spring 4 MVC project to learn the spring rest framework. This is a class project where I am creating a web app. I have managed to write some spring code from the various tutorials online. I am getting bean `autowiring` problem.

Error

```
Could not autowire field: taxApp.dao.daoImpl.userDaoImpl taxApp.controller.loginController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [taxApp.dao.daoImpl.userDaoImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency
```

These are the sample files

loginController.java

```
@RestController
public class loginController {
    @Autowired
    userDAO userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work
    //other methods
}
```

userDAO.java

```
public interface userDAO {
    public void insert(user _user);
    public user findUserByEmail(String email);
}
```

userDaoImpl.java

```
@Service("userDAO")
public class userDaoImpl implements userDAO{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;    

    //other methods
}
```

I have create the configuration files but kind of not sure if they are correctly placed. For example my dispatcher.xml in the web-inf folder while other xml files are in the resources. Also make sure that the class path is correct in all.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="taxApp" />
  <context:annotation-config />

  <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
      <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
      <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-user.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="userDAO" class="dao.impl.userDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <!-- Using Oracle datasource -->
  <import resource="database/data-source-cfg.xml" />
  <import resource="dao/spring-user.xml" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <!-- Spring MVC -->
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>

      <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>

      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The structure of my spring project looks like

```
src
   main
       java
           taxApp
                 controller
                           loginController.java
                 model
                      user.java
                 dao
                    userDaoImpl.java
                    userDAO.java
       resources
                database
                        data-source-cfg.xml
                user 
                    spring-user.xml
                spring-module.xml
       webapp
             web-inf
                    dispatcher-servlet.xml
                    web.xml
             index.jsp
```

Comment: Your naming choices are bad; none of them follow Java coding standards.  You're using Spring 4; I'd recommend not mixing XML and annotations.  Be consistent.  The messages on start up ought to make clear what's being loaded and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere you have imported spring-module.xml in dispatcher-servlet.xml. That's the reason your beans are not loaded in sprint context.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new in spring i suggest you to write full java config. That way you can debug your error more easily. Watch the following video to learn more

[Spring MVC with Intellij Full Java Config. No web.xml or Servlet.xml](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BY9YxdMg8I)

One more advice, Give capital later first to Class name & service/component name

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the following class in your class path,

```
<bean id="userDAO" class="dao.impl.userDaoImpl">
```

What it should be,

```
<bean id="userDAO" class="taxApp.dao.userDaoImpl">
```

It is because xml configuration takes precedence over Java configuration, and your xml configuration has broken.

Also if you remove above `userDAO` bean declaration from the xml, it will automatically will pick by using `@Service("userDAO")` and it should work then.

However you *should not* use both Java and xml configuration together without understanding Spring much. And your naming conversion is not likely java.